# How to re-write URL based on fetched JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, i18next

I am mapping through an array from JSON, where I get all the informations I need.

E.g. I have cards of **blog posts** fetched -> title, short description, published date and its url. So the card is linked based on the url from json - when I click I'll go to new page e.g -> click on blog n.1 -> redirect to **mywebsite/blogNumberOne**, but of course the page does not exist.

I have another JSON file, which have in the middle name of all the blogs -> so if I take that json and put the right parameter to it -> **(blogNumberOne)** -> it gives me new json with all the info from that post.

What I need to do is to connect it somehow and make my app to understand that now I click on blog n.1 so it has to go to /blogNumberOne and give me all the correct info from blog n.1. The same applies for each blog post of course.

I know I need to make the request to json, but I just don't know why.

Here is my fetch for printing out the blogs:

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch('myJSONurl')
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setGuides(data.guides);
                console.log(data);
            });
    }, []);


// mapping through

 {guides.map((blog) => {
                                return (
                                        <Card style={{ width: '15rem' }}>
                                            <Card.Img
                                                variant="top"
                                                src={blog.img}
                                            />
                                            <Card.Body>
                                                <Card.Title>
                                                    {blog.title}
                                                </Card.Title>
                                                <a
                                                    href={blog.url}
                                                    class="stretched-link"
                                                ></a>
                                            </Card.Body>
                                        </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `page` state in you app:

```
const [page, setpage] = useState(1);
```

Then on change of page, fetch it's respective data:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch data according to current page
  fetch(`${JSONURL}/${page}`)
},[page]);


// Then map the data
page.map(data => ....)
```

When you click on a blog post, it should have some `id` of some sort so you can fetch the data from it:

```
{
  posts.map(post => <BlogPost onClick={() => setPage(/*here mention something unique to each post to fetch data*/post.id)} />)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post @Shivam. I am trying to follow, but what exactly the line with `{posts.map(post => ..................` referes to ?